# How to save multiple downloaded excel files into .zip file using Angular2

Tags: angular, jszip

I have downloaded files and then saving all into zip from server :

```
const zipFile: JSZip = new JSZip();
for (let i = 0; i < sessionIds.length; i++) {
  this.getReport(id).toPromise()
    .then(
      (res) => {
        zipFile.file(res, 'test.xls', { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
      });
}
zipFile.generateAsync({ type: 'Blob' })
  .then((content) => {
    saveAs(content, 'content.zip');
  });
```

But the generated content.zip is empty, it is not saving any xls files into this. If I receive xls files one by one, it works. Please help me to save all files into .zip.

Answer (score 0):

you try to generate the zip before adding any report to the jsZip.

you have to wait for all report to be downloaded before calling zipFile.generateAsync

doc : [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

so try this :

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";
...

const zipFile: JSZip = new JSZip();

const reportObs: Observable<any>[] = sessionIds.map(id => {
    return this.getReport(id).map(res => {
        zipFile.file(res, 'test.xls', { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
    });
});

Observable.forkJoin(reportObs).subscribe(() => {
    zipFile.generateAsync({ type: 'Blob' })
      .then((content) => {
        saveAs(content, 'content.zip');
      });
});
```

Comment: Hi Pierre Mallet, Thank You for your help. I used the above code and now the content.zip which is getting generated is having nothing. Below is the file having one object. If I try to open this Object Blob in word document, it has one session id which passed to getReport function.